# How to show Arabic style in Google charts

Tags: css, asp.net, arabic

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Ar_PieChart.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ar_PieChart" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-16' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-height,minimum-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=3.0,user-scalable=yes" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Ar_PieChart.aspx/GetData',
                data: '{}',
                success:
                    function (response) {
                        drawVisualization(response.d);
                    }
            });
        })
        function drawVisualization(dataValues) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Column Name');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Column Value');
            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value]);
            }
            new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).draw(data, { is3D: true });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 350px">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Services;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class Ar_PieChart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Data> GetData()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=****;user id=****;Password=****;database=****");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        string cmdstr = "SELECT Class,COUNT(Class) FROM sh_report GROUP BY Class";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();
        string cat = "";
        int val = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            cat = dr[0].ToString();
            val = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
            dataList.Add(new Data(cat, val));
        }
        return dataList;
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public string ColumnName = "";
    public int Value = 0;
    public Data(string columnName, int value)
    {
        ColumnName = columnName;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

I am getting chart perfectly but i am in need of Arabic style like reverse.
 i mean while seeing the chart view in mirror.
 If any one know the answer please help me. 
Thanks in advance.